# Expand cell and add subviews to selected cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view which loads the data from web service such as label x3, button etc. Cell type is custom and I programmatically expand the cell and add subviews to it. Row expands fine and subview is added to the cell. Problem is that subview such as button is not only added to the selected cell but also to some other cells. How can I avoid subviews being added to other cells.

To refresh the specific cell on button click I use:

```
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNo inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method I use:

```
if (buttonPressed ==  YES)

{

 test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                test.frame = CGRectMake(10, 121, 260, 28);
  [cell.contentView addSubview:test];


}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the added subviews from cells that need it. Cells are reused as the table scrolls. You will keep adding more and more buttons to each cell.

Comment: How would I go about removing those subviews?

Comment: The same way you added them. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Add an `else` to your button check.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. What exactly should I add to the else part? If I add [test removeFromSuperview]; then view is never loaded.

Comment: Set the button's tag. Then you find the subview with that tag and remove it, if it exists.

Comment: I already have the button tag so how would I go about removing specific button with the tag, I am beginner. Also the first time I click the subview on button press it is created on other cells as well so not only selected cell. Why is that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the indexpath/indexpath.row of each cell on which button is pressed and add it to NSMutableArray.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath method check for button pressed:

```
if([self.buttonarray containsObject:indexpath) {
    //Code to add/remove button accordingly
    //Add button with tag as indexpath.row and for removal get the button with tag and remove button
    also remove the indexpath of button from self.button array
} else {
    //Code to add/remove button accordingly
    //Add button with tag as indexpath.row and for removal get the button with tag and remove button
    also remove the indexpath of button from self.button array      
}
```